# Solaris equivalent to OS X's pbcopy / pbpaste?

Tags: macos, solaris, clipboard, x11, pbcopy

OS X has nice commands for manipulating the clipboard:  [pbcopy and pbpaste](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pbcopy.1.html)

I could really use something similar in Solaris 10.  I've checked for [xsel and xclip](http://jetpackweb.com/blog/2009/09/23/pbcopy-in-ubuntu-command-line-clipboard/), and Solaris 10 doesn't have them.  Am I completely out of luck?

Comment: you can build xclip from source code on a solaris machine.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything quite equivalent on a system-wide basis for Solaris, because Solaris isn't a desktop operating environment. It *has* desktop OEs, but they're a layer on top of everything else and you cannot depend on them being there.

If you want, you can indeed build xclip from source. However, that's not a system-wide solution.

What problem are you trying to solve, btw?

Comment: By desktop operating environment, I assume you mean CDE, Gnome, etc.  At my workplace we're maintaining large Solaris applications (and still doing some active development on Solaris, while we simultaneously work on porting everything to Linux).

Comment: We use CDE and also Open Office running on Solaris. The problem I'm trying to solve is automating a repetitive process where 128 text files are opened, and their entire contents are copied, and then pasted into an Open Office spreadsheet. If I could put commands like 'cat file1 | pbcopy' into a script, that would take a significant amount of the drudgery out of it. Even if I were allowed to bring the xclip source code into our working environment (I'm not), I'm afraid I don't yet have the skill to build it.

Comment: Can't you cat all the files together and then import them into OpenOffice? If you can take the human out of this tedious-sounding process, then you'll have fewer errors.